# Problem with adding tables with TypeOrm and Nest.js

Tags: mysql, typeorm, nest

I am backend amatheur, you can see my project repo [here](https://github.com/BartoNatanael/LibraryBack). Today I added author entity and noticed that no table was added on data base. I deleted data-base completly but after that even one table wasn't created.

This is how my ormconfig.json looks:

```
"type": "mysql",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 8889,
"username": "root",
"password": "root",
"database": "Library",
"entities": ["dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}"],
"synchronize": false
}
```

I am launching mySql by MAMP (I am using MacOS).

Answer (score 0):

as MySQL is RDBMS (Relational Database) you must perform migrations every time you create or modify existing Entities. To automate the migration process I would suggest doing what TypeORM says in the [docs](http://%20https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations). Now in the docs, they describe how to do migration description on your own. But in [this section](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/migrations#generating-migrations) TypeORM says it is possible to automate the migration code. There you should see this piece of CLI code:

```
typeorm migration:generate -n PostRefactoring
```

Let me explain the code above. `typeorm` is the CLI command to refer to typeorm-related tools. `migration:generate` is for generating the migration code. `-n PostRefactoring` is the naming of the migration file where the migration code is placed.

Obviously in your `ormconfig.json`, you didn't include the entity and migration files folder.

```
"migrations": [
    // string can contain regular expressions
    'your/path-to/entities/*.ts', // sample: 'src/modules/*.entity.ts'
],
"cli": {
  // string can contain regular expressions here too
  migrationsDir: 'src/migrations',
}
```

After generating the migration file which contains the information for the database to update and/or create, you easily run:

```
typeorm migration:run
```

The code above automatically finds the latest updates in the migrations folder and apply the updates to your connection db.

Hope it helped you.